# explorer not showing xml

Tags: internet-explorer-8

I'm geberating some xml with a web service, I can open the url in Firefox, but I get "Internet Explorer cannot display the webpage" in explorrer, the url is like this:
http://192.168.50.171:8080/Webservices/Dis/GetAs?MType=2

If I save the file using firefox I can then open it in explorer!!

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<GetAreasByMetricTypeResponseElement>
<Areas>
<Area>
<LevelTypeId>DistrictOrUnitary</LevelTypeId>
<AreaId>1</AreaId>
<Name>Slough Borough Council</Name>
</Area>
<Area>
<LevelTypeId>DistrictOrUnitary</LevelTypeId>
<AreaId>35</AreaId>
<Name>City of London</Name>
</Area>
</Areas>
</GetAreasByMetricTypeResponseElement>
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Please, post here source of that XML file, as we cannot connect to your given link.

Comment: What Content-Type header are you setting for your page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't solved the problem (just not a priority anymore) but it is related with the content type header. This needs to be changed to a supported one.